# Azure AD SSO Redirection After Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I'm unable to correctly redirect the dashboard.aspx page after authentication using OAUTH and Azure AD. When I debug in VS 2017 I'm able to sign in using my O365 email and password and redirection works perfectly. However, when I publish to the web server it does not. The page just seems to sit there and not do anything. I've tried changing the redirection URL in Azure to http://domainame.com/dashboard.aspx however this doesn't work. I had also placed a redirect statement in the code behind file as well. I'm needing to get this application deployed and this is the last piece that I need. This is using OWIN as well. I used the default ASP.NET template to start the project and chose authentication from work or school.
Below is the StartUpAuth.cs file. I change the actual redirect domain to domain.name.com for posting purposes only. I apologize if the code isn't formatted correctly. Every time I try I still get voted down on it regardless of if there are 4 indents or not.

```
namespace HealthScripts
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        private string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;
        // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
        private static string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    //RedirectUri = "https://domain.name.com/HealthScripts-Staging/",
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        //
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        //
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                );

            // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1379
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +452
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +927
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +109
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1550
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +258
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +314
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +255
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +128
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +101
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +509
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +561
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +231
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +911
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +117
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +211
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +125
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +156
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +292
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +187
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +69
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +482
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +174
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +269
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +59
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +61
   HealthScripts.Models.ADALTokenCache..ctor(String signedInUserId) in C:\Users\tadams\Desktop\Important Projects\HS-MAIN\HealthScripts\HealthScripts\Models\AdalTokenCache.cs:14
   HealthScripts.Startup.<ConfigureAuth>b__7_0(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context) in C:\Users\tadams\Desktop\Important Projects\HS-MAIN\HealthScripts\HealthScripts\App_Start\StartupAuth.cs:54
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +5389
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +5898
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +817
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +329
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +768
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +194
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +184
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +117
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +365
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

Comment: When it "seems to sit there", do you see anything in the console or the network tab of the browser? It may have a response or error.

Comment: I'm not seeing any response errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The system cannot find the file specified." This error message means the client can reach the server but there is no Named Pipe listener with a specific a pipe name on the target machine. It also means that the account can have a file sharing session without a problem.

Possible reasons are:

a) Typo in instance name or wrong instance name. The instance name is not the one you are targeting. Note that for the default instance, you shouldn't use MSSQLSERVER as instance name.

b) Target SQL Server is not running

c) Named Pipe is not enabled on the server.

d) You are using different versions and dependencies are missing.

Make sure you can connect to SQL Server manually using SSMS. If so, then update the connection string inside application's web.config. If you cannot connect to SQL Server using SSMS, then you need to troubleshoot the problem: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your SSO works locally it will not work in the published version, and vice versa. Check to ensure that the reply URLs are set to the published app URL in the Azure portal and in the code configuration.

For reference, see this documentation: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

Comment: I've attached the stack trace after making adjustments based off of Marilee T - MSFT link. I'm not sure why it is still trying to look for a local DB connection or even use the local path. I'm using a remote connection to an SQL server.